# Call a controller's method from an external ruby script

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rabbitmq

I'm creating an external service of my rails app. This is always listening a rabbitmq queue and all their messages should be redirected to some methods of the rails controllers.
I've tried these approaches:

[AMQP subscriber inside Rails app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2835143/amqp-subscriber-inside-rails-app/7053153#7053153)

[What's the correct way to run one controller action from another controller action without an HTTP redirect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/809028/whats-the-correct-way-to-run-one-controller-action-from-another-controller-acti/870168#870168)

http://www.misuse.org/science/2007/07/24/firing-rails-controller-actions-from-command-line-console/

The first one allowed me only to access the model (Anyway I suppose must be the base for what I want). The second one... never worked for me. And the last one doesn't works on rails 3 ( ActionController::Integration doesn't exists)

I think that the last approach still could be used if I figure out how the sessions are handled in rails 3. In any case, somebody had tried something similar before? Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just send the request via an HTTP request? Your controller basically makes actions visible via URLs - simply making a request to the URL is essentially the same as calling the controller code, and it keeps your code working like a software service/API. You could even just use `curl` to do this if you want.

Otherwise, if the two files are in the same machine/folder, you could try to explicitly include the one controller code in the other, but that seems like maybe not the way to go. Depends on how you want the end result to work.

Comment: I'm thinking to use http request as the last option. Basically for a performance issue. Access directly to a controller should be faster than through http requests. About include the controller's code, the idea should have a DRY code